# Is there a faster way to level Speech in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There used to be a way to level Speech quick by talking to Ungrien in Riften and using the Persuade option many times, but it was patched. Is there any faster way of boosting Speech? I'm at 67 on Speech now.

Comment: One more thing I couldn't delete the patch in my xbox 360.

Comment: It isn't a duplicate because the accepted answer is no longer valid.  The other answers are a bit lacking.  UESP links in my answer basically has all the tried and tested ways to level speech.

Comment: @Nelson - Answer acceptance doesn't mean much - votes matter more. Besides, the questions ARE identical, if you have a problem with the answers on the other question then you should update them or post your own there. (Be sure to preserve the original point of the answer when updating, don't change a 'no' to a 'yes' for example). Leave a comment requesting an update and downvote the ones that are completely wrong, even if they were right before.

Comment: The other issue is the age of the "duplicate" question.  It is 2 years old with obsolete answers, and new answers will be buried below much older and outdated answers.

Comment: Watch this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kn0aYIfnr6o

Answer (score 2):

By far, the fastest way possible is to throw money at a [Master Speech Trainer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speech#Trainers).

However, if you do not have a large amount of money, you can instead make really expensive items (Alchemy, Blacksmith, Enchanting) and selling them.  There are [additional methods of training](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speech#Gaining_Skill_XP) available.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easier way, on the long process, is to sell stuff to merchant. Not just expensive things but pretty much any junk you can get your hands on and can be sold. The percentage is low but it adds up.

You can also try to buy and sell the items back to the merchant... you lose some money but it can be really helpful towards levelling up your skill.

A very effective way to level up your speech is to steal from the guards and then persuade them to overlook it. This will only work once if it's the same guard. So only once per guard.